# Animation translate doesn't work properly

Tags: css, animation, transform, translate, drop

I wanna make a drop animation when the page loads similar to a working example I've seen at someone else but mine doesn't. The image doesn't drop at all, does not transition from 0 opacity to 1 opacity. It just suddenly appears after the given duration. Help me, please.

```
.cover img{
    height: 60vh;
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 5px 3px black);
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
    animation: drop 1.5s ease;
}
@keyframes drop{
    0% {
        opacity: 0%;
        transform: translateY(-80px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1%;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you've done wrong is used a percentage in the opacity. You just need the number.

```
@keyframes drop {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-80px);
    }
    100% { 
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi, it did, thank you. Also, do you know why in the first milliseconds of the animation only a part of the image is visible? It's like a glitch... Could it be because I have a slow device?

Comment: You could try compressing your image so it takes less time to download. That normally works. Also, a more expensive option would be to host it on a CDN. (content delivery network)